# Configuring a jar to read properties from file using property manager and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, tomcat7

First, I apologize if this question is titled incorrectly.

**Goal: I am using maven to package a jar that needs to read an external properties file. The jar will be used by wars that will be deployed using tomcat7. In tomcat, setenv.sh as shown below location of properties file (PROPERTY_MANAGER) is set from where the jar will read the properties. How can I do this?**

I am using Apache-tomcat-7.0.32 and my **setenv.sh** reads:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-DPROPERTY_MANAGER=$CATALINA_HOME/myPropertiesDir -DCOMMON_PROPERTIES=$CATALINA_HOME/myCommonPropsDir -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=pass $JAVA_OPTS"
```

In eclipse I import an existing maven module. My module at this point is a simple java class (so I can test how properties are read via tomcat). Here is my class:

```
Class MyClass{
 private String var1;
 private String var2;
 public MyClass(){}
 public String getVar1() { return var1; }
 public String getVar2() { return var2; }
 public String setVar1(String a) { var1 = a; }
 public String setVar2(String a) { var2 = b; }
 public static void main (String []arg){
   MyClass c = new MyClass();
   System.out.println(“var1 = “ + c.getVar1() +”, var2 = “+c.getVar2());
 }
}// end of class
```

Here is the **myprops.xml** file under src/main/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance    
       xmlns:si=http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
       xmlns:jms=http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
       xmlns:context=http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       xmlns:util=http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context              
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">                     

      <context:property-placeholder location="file:${PROPERTY_MANAGER}/myclass-props.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/> 
      <!-- MyClass bean -->
      <bean id="mybean" class="my.com.test.MyClass">
        <property name="var1" value="${prop.var1}" />
        <property name="var2" value="${prop.var2}" />
     </bean>
 </beans>
```

**myclass-props** is located under $CATALINA_HOME/myCommonPropsDir and looks like this:

```
prop.var1=abc
prop.var2=123
```

The above class is build as a maven module and packaged as a jar. In order to test this, I started tomcat and then in Eclipse tried running the main class as Java Application and debugging it as Remote Java Application. The remote one does nothing. Running it as java app gives me the following output: 
     var1 = null, var2 = null;

Clearly the property file wasn't picked up. What am I doing wrong here? I am sure its something small I am missing. Thanks for all suggestions in advance.

Comment: The main method you are invoking is not on the Spring managed object  (but the one created `new MyClass()`)and hence its properties are not injected/initialized.

Comment: @Santosh not sure I follow. When I instantiate the class shouldn't the properties be injected therefore whether main() is spring managed or not wouldn't be an issue?

Comment: When **YOU** instantiate the class, You are _not using spring at all_ and hence there wont be any property injection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is `${PROPERTY_MANAGER}` was not substituted with the sysprop (maven sysprop substitution is completely different to spring). If your goal is to make the jar read an external property file without hardcoding the location, use classpath instead:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/myclass-props.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Then you can place the file on $TOMCAT_HOME/lib or any other folder included to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Santosh is right. There's nothing bringing up your spring context.

When you run it as a java application from Eclipse, the `main` method code is simply executed. In the `main` method you create an instance of the `MyClass` - that's not the way you create spring beans. Spring won't inject properties or bean references to classes created with the `new` keyword. Also, Eclipse doesn't deploy your jar on Tomcat when you run it.

Try creating a web app with a spring context containing a bean which will use your properties reading module (as you've described in your question) and then test if it works. Don't use the `new` keyword to create an instance of the `MyClass`, but inject the bean declared in your context. You can create the context in you `main` method, but it won't be run on the application server.

I suggest reading [Spring Framework's documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-introduction) a bit (especially the part about bean instantiation and dependency injection).